# pylearn2 resume Training of the Model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pylearn

I am using pylearn2 to train a neural net. Here's the YAML file I am using: https://github.com/goodfeli/adversarial/blob/master/cifar10_convolutional.yaml

I used this command to start a training session in linux terminal:

```
$ pylearn2-train <Name of YAML File>
```

The model is being saved as pickle file after every epoch. However, the training was interrupted in between. How do I resume the training ?